# How to implement abstract class methods as static method in inherited class in python?

Tags: python, inheritance

I am working on python 2.7.
I need to implement a class having abstract method. All the methods of this class should be implemented as static method.

Example:-

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod


class HelperABC(object):

    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    @abstractmethod
    def method_name(my_message):
        pass
```

In the above class i need to take method_name(my_message) and implement it as static method.

I want to use it as:-

```
@staticmethod
def method_name(my_message):
   "code"
```

Please tell me how to implement it.

I try to put both decorator @staticmethod and @abstractmethod like following:-

```
@abstractmethod
@staticmethod
def method_name(my_message):
    pass
```

This also did not work.

Comment: What is your issue with the first try - only `@staticmethod` ?

Comment: @AnandSKumar When i use only @staticmethod, it shows something like following in the implemented class:-


    `@staticmethod
    def method_name(my_message):
        HelperABC.debug(my_message)`

In the implemented class, it is making an object of abstract class. So, i think this is not a proper way to use abstract class in python.

Answer (score 1):

Modify your method as below. I tried and it worked for me:

```
@staticmethod
@abstractmethod
def method_name(my_message):
    pass
```

Comment: aggregation of properties introduced in python 3.3